# What is meant by "quantum steering"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, foundations

I have become interested in quantum steering after listening a talk and tried to read more about it. I think I am more confused now. My understanding is as follows:

> Sharing a (entangled) state, Bob wants to make a series of
>   measurements  and  Alice wants to make a guess of the measurement
>   outcome.

After which I am totally at loss, as a few papers which I have seen refers to a steering inequality. However it is heavily state dependent, and not like Bell (or Bell type) inequalities. Can someone point out some basic references or clear up my confusion. I am sorry for not writing it more clearly. May be by the questions, I shall be able to understand.  Advanced thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have the link to the talk (if it was videoed )?
I am interested and would like to watch it.

Comment: the standard reference here is [Wiseman et al. 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0612147)